# input/output parameters in prolog definition

Tags: prolog

Is there any difference between the input/output parameters in prolog definitions? How does this this compare with other languages such as scheme and C ?

Answer (score 4):

well, there are differencies between input and output parameters, but let's illustrate with an example:

```
?- length([1, 2, 3], 3).
true.
```

Here our arguments are all input, and the predicate is used as a test.

```
?- length([1, 2, 3], L).
L = 3.
```

Here our arguments are `+`, `-`. The predicate is used as a list length calculator.

```
?- length(X, 3).
X = [_A, _B, _C].
```

Here our arguments are `-`, `+`. The predicate is used as a list skeleton generator.

```
?- length(X, L).
X = [], L = 0;
X = [_A], L = 1;
X = [_A, _B], L = 2;
% etc, infinite.
```

Here our arguments are `-`, `-`. The predicate is used as a generator for list of larger and larger lengths.

So `length/2` doesn't really make any difference between an input and and output parameter, it only serves different purposes depending on the way it is called.

On the other hand:

```
?- X is 3 + 2.
X = 5.
```

works, while

```
?- 5 is A + 2.
```

throws an insufficiently instantiated parameter error... If you think about it, it's quite normal, because to give an answer in all cases, `is/2` would have to be a pretty advanced solver...

I hope those examples will help you make the difference between the different types of parameters.