# Difference between the input/output parameters in prolog

Tags: prolog, parameter-passing

Is there any difference between input and output parameters in Prolog predicate definitions? How does this this compare with other languages such as Scheme and C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [input/output parameters in prolog definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002546/input-output-parameters-in-prolog-definition)

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand your question. You should look into how unification is implemented in Prolog, as it will make things clearer. Anyway:

Briefly, there is no built-in way to declare an argument to a Prolog predicate as input, output, or input/output.

In C, you could say:

```
void foo(int const *a, int *b)
{
    *b += *a;
}
```

and you could argue that in the context of `foo`, `a` is an input argument, while `b` is an output argument. In Prolog, you can use [this notation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/preddesc.html%27%29%29) when describing predicates, but there is no way to **declare** in the head of the predicate definition that an argument **must** be bound or a free variable when the predicate is called. And anyway, most predicates in pure Prolog have arguments that can be *input*, *output*, or *input/output*, depending how the predicate is used. Look [at the list library of SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29) for many examples.

You can of course demand that an argument is instantiated, or a free variable, but this is done in the body of the predicate definition:

```
add_2(A, B) :- integer(A), var(B), B is A+2.
```

Compare this to:

```
plus_2(A, B) :- integer(A), integer(B), B =:= A+2.
```

which checks whether B=A+2 holds true, instead of adding 2 to A and unifying the result with B. `integer/1`, `var/1`, and the [other predicates that verify the type of a term](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.6%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/typetest.html%27%29%29) cannot be implemented in pure Prolog.

In my very limited experience with Prolog, I have noticed that one will try to define predicates that work as long as enough arguments are instantiated to either:

1. Instantiate the other variables according to the logic of the predicate
2. Infer whether the relationship between the arguments described by the predicate holds true.

For example, `length(List, Integer)` can tell you how long a list is, make a list of uninstantiated variables of the given length, or check whether the list is that long.

What you can do, however, is have a ground term in the head of the predicate definition, for example `foo(1)`. This sort of predicates are called *facts*. A clause with a ground term in the head is the usual way for defining the end-of-recursion for recursive predicates.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference between the input/output parameters in Prolog definitions?

No, and in fact a parameter can be either one depending on how it is used. Boris's length example is a good one, because you can calculate length:

```
?- length([1,2,3], X).
X = 3.
```

Or test an answer:

```
?- length([1,2,3], 3).
true.
```

Or generate a list of specified length:

```
?- length(X, 3).
X = [_G273, _G276, _G279].
```

Or even generate lists and lengths:

```
?- length(X, Y).
X = [],
Y = 0 ;
X = [_G15],
Y = 1 ;
X = [_G15, _G18],
Y = 2 ;
...
```

So you see either argument of `length/2` can be instantiated or not and you'll still get meaningful answers. Not every predicate in Prolog is this flexible, but many are.

> How does this this compare with other languages such as scheme and C ?

This is *the principal difference* between Prolog and other languages. There is no other, better-known language which behaves analogously to help you grok it. It means that, among other differences, there is no implicit "return value," you must have a parameter to pass results back in, but you're not limited to just one result parameter. In the case where both arguments to `length/2` were uninstantiated, they were both acting as return values.

By convention, you will want to write your predicates so that input parameters go before output parameters for the common cases (or at least, in a sensible way for the name you've chosen).

Comment: damn we have the exact same examples ;) see the duplicate question in OP comments =)

Comment: @Mog Damn. :) I was borrowing Boris's. Voted to close.

Comment: @Mog Damn, someone is crowd-sourcing their homework again... I missed that previous question and your answer, otherwise I wouldn't have made the effort.

Comment: @Boris: yup and up until the duplicate I had no clue it was some homework assignment directly pasted ;(

Comment: It really bugs me how hard it is to get something closed in the Prolog area. Seems like between the lot of us there's only three people who vote to close.

Comment: "Not every predicate in Prolog is this flexible, but many are." Is there any example of a predicate implementable or included in pure Prolog, which is not usable in both directions. All the examples, which are not usable in both directions, use non-logical components like the arithmetic ````is````.