# Removing duplicates from list and returning modified list prolog

Tags: prolog

Prolog predicate to take in a list and remove duplicates then return the modified list back.

The below code works well for removing duplicates and returning it however it is taking two parameters. How can i achieve the same result taking 1 parameter? example remove_duplicates(List).

```
remove_duplicates([],[]).
remove_duplicates([X|Y],Z):-
  member(X,Y),
  !,
  remove_duplicates(Y,Z). 
remove_duplicates([X|Y],[X|Z]):-
  remove_duplicates(Y,Z).
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want some kind of "call-by-reference"-style attribute?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008754/difference-between-the-input-output-parameters-in-prolog for why 2 arguments is the sensible number.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want in prolog (modify an instantiated part of a term) without using [destructive assignment predicates](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=setarg), which are discouraged and should not be used in your problem.

The following code does what you want for instantiated lists using `setarg/3` to destructively modify a term, but is not recommended:

```
% Warning: this procedure uses destructive assignment predicates
da_remove_duplicates(L):-  
  setof(X, member(X, L), [First|Rest]), % may use this instead: remove_duplicates(L, [First|Rest]),
  setarg(1, L, First),
  setarg(2, L, Rest).
da_remove_duplicates([]).
```

Sample run:

```
?- L=[1,1,3],da_remove_duplicates(L).
L = [1, 3].
```

Comment: so you recommend going with an approach where 2 inputs are taken rather 1? Can you further explain why it is not recommended this way ?

Comment: Yes, you should write a procedure with two arguments. When writing prolog always try to think about relations. Your original program although is not pure as it uses ! is easy to follow and understand in which modes it can be used (for example the first argument a ground list and the second a free variable). Using destructive assignment predicates make your program very difficult to understand and prone to errors.

Comment: For example, take the sample run and add a second unification like this: `L=[1,1,3],da_remove_duplicates(L), L=[1,3].`. This query actually succeeds but it does not make sense from a logical point of view. How can a variable `L` unify with both lists `[1,1,3]` and `[1,3]` ? It should't but it does because of the destructive assignment.

Comment: Great! Regarding the answer you posted. what if i dont want to have L outside. I want to call the predicate like this remove_duplicates([1,1,3,2,4,2,6]).

Comment: It will succeed but you won't be able to see the results